# why Object is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to implement the modification function with React and TypeScript. When the edit button is clicked, detailed data is received from the container and passed to the component's props. However, if you go ahead and print it to the console log, the data object appears well, but if you try to put it in the initial state value, such an undefine error occurs. How can I fix it?

Or, if you can tell me how to put the initial state value, I would appreciate it. First, I put the default value attribute in the input UI, but the state is the problem.

```
interface UpdateRecruitProps {
  onUpdateRecruit: (data: object) => void;
  initData: InitRecruitData | undefined;
  status: boolean;
  error: string;
}

const UpdateRecruit: React.FC<UpdateRecruitProps> = ({ onUpdateRecruit, initData, status, error }) => {
  console.log(initData);
  const nameRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
    person: initData.other.personnel,
    name: nameRef.current?.defaultValue,
```

... other state and datas

```
<S.InputLine type="text"
             name="person"
             ref={personRef}
             onChange={onChangeInput}
             defaultValue={initData?.other.personnel}></S.InputLine>
```

Comment: in line `person: initData.other.personnel` should probably be `person: initData?.other.personnel` since `initData` might be undefined

Comment: Yes I know that. If you do that, you will get an error. It may be because it can be undefined. But I want the state to contain that value. How can it be done?